# PyQt5 loop images sequence automaticaly

Tags: image, python-2.7, animation, pyqt5

i add code to my app to open images sequence with two buttons prev and next.
how i can set the next button clicked every second for example to play the sequence ?

```
def nextitem(self):
    self.listWidget.sortItems()
    #a = self.choice2.text()
    count = self.listWidget.count()
    cur = self.listWidget.currentRow()
    self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(cur+1)
    if (cur+1) == count:
        self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(0)
    if len(self.choice2.text()) > 0:
        tex = self.listWidget.currentItem().text()
        a = self.video_choice_2.setText(tex)
    self.playVideo2()
```

[image]

**UPDATE**
i find a function in the forum and it work but i can't stop the animation or do anything else .

```
    import time
    repeat_time = 0.3
    while True:
        start_time = time.time()
        self.nextitem()
        time.sleep(max(repeat_time - (time.time() - start_time), 0.0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use time.sleep because it will lock the process. Use QTimer from PyQt5.QtCore instead. Google has tonnes of examples of how to use QTimer.

Comment: thanks ; i find a good example : http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@p@y@pyqt5-HEAD@examples@designer@plugins@widgets@bubbleswidget.py/126/PyQt5.QtCore.QTimer

Answer (score 0):

i find solution and it work good but when i click on play button twice or many times the speed increased and i can't stop the animation.

```
def playSeq(self):
    self.animation_timer = QTimer(self)
    self.animation_timer.setSingleShot(False)
    self.animation_timer.timeout.connect(self.nextitem)
    self.animation_timer.start(300)
```

UPDATE : Problem solved
before when i clicked it always call Qtimer but now it call start only

```
    self.animation_timer = QTimer(self)
    self.animation_timer.setSingleShot(False)
    self.animation_timer.timeout.connect(self.nextitem)
def playSeq(self):      
     self.animation_timer.start(300)
```

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: this is another question in the same topic ; why i need ask again and than someone - and i am sure- will comment like your comment : don't ask the same question, please if you can't help don't comment

Comment: do you have a solution ?